# Iterate through an array of objects Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

Need some help with this, been stuck for hours.

Trying to iterate through an array of objects in node to grab one of the key's value and perform a regex function.

I keep getting undefined reading errors, the latest one is

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

The array is created by calling `toArray()` on a MongoDB collection find function:

```json
"ups": [
  {
    "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f5289e",
    "article_code": "4325832",
    "order_number": "",
    "status": "shipped",
    "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
    "unique_id": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f528b4",
    "article_code": "6242665",
    "order_number": "",
    "status": "shipped",
    "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
    "unique_id": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f528ef",
    "article_code": "3610890",
    "order_number": "",
    "status": "shipped",
    "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
    "unique_id": ""
  }
]
```

Here's my code attempt:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++) {       
    var ups_tt = i['tt_url'];
    var unique_id = i['unique_id'];
        
    var spl = ups_tt.split(/tracknum=(.*)/)[1];
    ups_tt = spl.split("&")[0];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your variable 'ups' that you are using in for statement?

Comment: Your latest error means that the object has no `tt_url` property. Make sure to debug and inspect your variables as you run the code with break points. It is so much easier when you spot that a variable has not the expected value.

Comment: change var ups_tt = i['tt_url'] with var ups_tt = ups[i]['tt_url'] .   i  is just an integer

Comment: hahaha damn im dumb. cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the url is simple enough, you can just directly split it by "&", no need to use regex

so:

```
ups_tt = ups_tt.split('&')[2];
var spl = "&" + ups_tt;
```

Comment: ended up doing this too, thank you for suggesting

Answer (score 0):

so, in your example, `i` is just a number, so if you try to get a key of a number, then you will get undefined

```
> let i = 1;
undefined
> i["test"]
undefined
```

what you should do is reference the array `ups` with the index:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++){
       
        var ups_tt = ups[i].tt_url;
        var unique_id = ups[i].unique_id;
        
        var spl = ups_tt.split(/tracknum=(.*)/)[1];
        ups_tt = spl.split("&")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
let y = {
  "ups": [
    {
      "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f5289e",
      "article_code": "4325832",
      "order_number": "",
      "status": "shipped",
      "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
      "unique_id": ""
    }, {
      "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f528b4",
      "article_code": "6242665",
      "order_number": "",
      "status": "shipped",
      "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
      "unique_id": ""
    }, {
      "_id": "61b5ef3a8bec102408f528ef",
      "article_code": "3610890",
      "order_number": "",
      "status": "shipped",
      "tt_url": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=999&requester=ST/trackdetails",
      "unique_id": ""
    }
  ]
}
    
y.ups.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element)
});
```

Comment: console.log(element.article_code) you can access the value like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**The error is on row `var spl = ups_tt.split(/tracknum=(.*)/)[1];`, because `ups_tt` is undefined.**

> ```js
> for(let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++){
>       
>     var ups_tt = i['tt_url'];
>     var unique_id = i['unique_id'];
>
>     var spl = ups_tt.split(/tracknum=(.*)/)[1];
>     ups_tt = spl.split("&")[0];
> ```

`i` is the index so it's a number. You could fix it adding either `let elem = ups[i]` inside the loop, or changing `i[property]` to `ups[i][property]`:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < ups.length; i++){
    // A
    let elem = ups[i];
    var ups_tt = elem['tt_url'];
    var unique_id = elem['unique_id'];

    // B
    var ups_tt = ups[i]['tt_url'];
    var unique_id = ups[i]['unique_id'];

    // rest of the loop
```

Also, since you're also asking how to iterate an array of objects, you could use [for .. of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), built exactly to do that:

> The **`for...of` statement** creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

Your code would look like this:

```js
for (let elem of ups) {
    var ups_tt = elem['tt_url'];
    var unique_id = elem['unique_id'];

    var spl = ups_tt.split(/tracknum=(.*)/)[1];
    ups_tt = spl.split("&")[0];

    // rest of the loop
```

There's other ways, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) has a very comprehensive comparison between different ways to loop arrays, or even other types of objects.

Last point, because there's some answers using *dot notation*: since ups is the array with various elements where every element is an object, instead of `elem['tt_url']`, you can access their properties using dot, like `elem.tt_url`, but in this case, that's mostly a matter of preference. In some cases, however, the only option is to use array notation: if you're using a string inside a variable as key, or if the property has some special characters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for more info.